# Laravel Livewire - String validation doesn't work

Tags: laravel, string, validation, input, laravel-livewire

Basically i have a method for validating my input fields

```
public function validateData()
{
    if($this->currentStep == 1){
        $this->validate([
            "name" => "required|string|max:255",
            "lastname" => "required|string",
            "email" => "required|email|unique:users",
            "mobile" => "required|string",
            "password" => "required|string"
        ]);
    }elseif($this->currentStep == 2){
        $this->validate([
            "address" => "required|string",
            "municipality" => "required|string",
            "profile_image" => "required|url",
            "biography" => "required|string"
        ]);
    }
}
```

All of my validation rules are working except the `string` rule. Has anyone encountered this problem before, or is it a bug?

Comment: What error do you get? Any examples of what input validates as string and what input doesn't?

Comment: @brombeer I don't get an error, if for example i add a number to the input field the string rule is ignored, but it shouldn't

Comment: Are you maybe looking for the https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-alpha validation?

Comment: An input type text always returns a string value, even if characters inside the string may be considered numeric. `"0"` is simply a string. Follow Brombeer's advice if you want purely alphabetic characters.